# Handling various parsing operations with a single delegate

Tags: ios, delegates, nsxmlparser

I have a custom class and I want it to be able to handle various parsing operations (using `AFXMLRequestOperation`) differently.

I would prefer for this one custom class to be its own delegate for both operations, meaning the parser delegate methods would need to be able to determine which operation they should be handling. Is that a standard practice? And if so, how is it typically managed? I could simply set a property on my class to A or B and check its value in the delegate methods, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution or if I'm missing something/misconceptualizing the problem.

(I know that `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods get passed the initiating connection and can examine it; but for `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods, I define an `AFXMLRequestOperation`, which does not get passed to the delegate methods; rather, the NSXMLParser defined in the operation's completion block gets passed to the delegate methods; is there some way I can use that to pass identifying info to the delegate methods?)

Thank you

Comment: You can always tack custom data onto any instance with associated objects; that's one way to do it. You could also add an idenitifier property to `NSXMLParser` in a category. Also, does it have to be one _instance_ that's the delegate for both parsers? If not, there's no problem; each delegate instance will only get callbacks for its particular parser.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Adding an identifier property in a category seems like a decent solution. No, it does not have to be one instance. But, given that each instance will have identical delegate methods, how does that help me identify the parser? Thanks!

Comment: Because each delegate instance will have its own dictionary or string or whatever you're using to store the parser results.